# lots of simultaneous connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, scalability, websocket

I'm working on chat application. The underlying server uses Node.js and the client/server communication goes via WebSockets.

So the question is: how many simultaneous connections can such a server handle (without visible lags)? Of course approximately and assuming that the server is very powerful machine. I know this is not an easy question to answer but I just want ideas, some approximations... or at least upper and lower bounds. Of course I'm going to do some practical tests, but the theory may help me a bit.

Also I have another question related to the first one: is it possible to split Node.js applications into multiple machines? Keep in mind, that most of the data is held in machines memory rather then database.

Waiting for replies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you run node.js on top of epoll/kqueue and tune your OS for high TCP connection numbers.

Here are a couple of measured numbers for a publish/subscribe system based on Autobahn WebSockets:

- 180k concurrent, active WebSocket connections
- 12k/s dispatched pubsub messages
- 4k/s WebSocket opening handshakes
- <8kB per WebSocket connection

This is on a FreeBSD i386 virtual machine configured with 2 cores and 2GB RAM.

Autobahn WebSockets is Python/Twisted based and runs on a kqueue reactor.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [simple benchmark of a multiroom chat application](https://github.com/jgonera/socket.io-multichat). Just remember to monitor the CPU% when running it, it's possible that the benchmark app will drain the CPU faster than the server!